# Why does code A runs well whereas B got an error?

Tags: pytorch

I encountered a question when I try to understand a line of code:
`scores = [s[tuple(k.t())] for s, k in zip(scores, keypoints)]`.
Here I am going to give the code that can reproduce it:

```
import torch # v1.5.1

scores = [torch.rand(480, 640)]
keypoints = [torch.randint(0, 480, [978, 2])]

scores = [s[tuple(k.t())] for s, k in zip(scores, keypoints)] # label A, OK

for s, k in zip(scores, keypoints):
    print(s[tuple(k.t())]) # label B, Error

>>> IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
```

I think the above two kinds of code (A and B respectively) are almost the same, but the latter threw out an error. I discussed it with my roommate but we have no idea what's going on.

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the *exact text of this error* didn't seem relevant to the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why this error came out here and maybe don't have a great description of it.

Comment: Could it be because you re-defined scores to be label A?

Comment: Thanks! I re-defined the scores and didn't notice haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the order of A and B, for you have already changed "scores" when you execute B. It will definitely works.

```
import torch
scores = [torch.rand(2, 3)]
keypoints = [torch.randint(0, 2, [4, 2])]

for s, k in zip(scores, keypoints):
    print(s[tuple(k.t())]) # label B, Error (now ok)

scores = [s[tuple(k.t())] for s, k in zip(scores, keypoints)] # label A, OK
print(scores)
```

The output is

```
[tensor([0.3175, 0.6934, 0.2842, 0.3175])]
[tensor([0.3175, 0.6934, 0.2842, 0.3175])]
```

which is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are redefining what `scores` is and therefore the values change. However if you change the line

```
scores = [s[tuple(k.t())] for s, k in zip(scores, keypoints)]
```

to:

```
labelA = [s[tuple(k.t())] for s, k in zip(scores, keypoints)]
```

It should be the same.

```
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> scores = [torch.rand(480, 640)]
>>> keypoints = [torch.randint(0, 480, [978, 2])]
>>>
>>>
>>> labelA =  [s[tuple(k.t())] for s, k in zip(scores, keypoints)] # label A, OK
>>> labelB = []
>>> for s, k in zip(scores, keypoints):
...     labelB.append(s[tuple(k.t())])
...
>>> labelB
[tensor([0.7239, 0.1610, 0.6094, 0.8368, 0.1523, 0.1063, 0.6487, 0.8021, 0.0650,
        0.5950, 0.3393, 0.7012, 0.6868, 0.8905, 0.4100, 0.8173, 0.2271, 0.7572,
        0.9446, 0.4321, 0.5575, 0.4204, 0.8950, 0.2369, 0.1743, 0.8011, 0.3178,
        0.8098, 0.1318, 0.2499, 0.2979, 0.4248, 0.7016, 0.5042, 0.5122, 0.0894,
        0.6981, 0.9588, 0.9439, 0.6145, 0.1386, 0.0325, 0.6099, 0.5928, 0.1368,
        0.3560, 0.5814, 0.8894, 0.5715, 0.3138, 0.2881, 0.0041, 0.2198, 0.2518,
        0.7856, 0.9828, 0.0374, 0.1621, 0.8600, 0.9820, 0.9233, 0.1292, 0.3045,
        0.5753, 0.6036, 0.7019, 0.2679, 0.5477, 0.2112, 0.7881, 0.3429, 0.2112,
        0.3397, 0.6253, 0.2414, 0.0650, 0.4213, 0.0078, 0.5286, 0.1454, 0.5127,
        0.9211, 0.2263, 0.7103, 0.6328, 0.4127, 0.5828, 0.5850, 0.3128, 0.6189,
        0.0670, 0.5370, 0.3466, 0.8870, 0.0481, 0.4839, 0.0507, 0.1635, 0.6603,
        0.6537, 0.6107, 0.0907, 0.0952, 0.8440, 0.5431, 0.4123, 0.2333, 0.0709,
        0.3717, 0.5081, 0.6989, 0.7998, 0.4175, 0.4417, 0.4483, 0.4192, 0.4145,
        0.3055, 0.1455, 0.8435, 0.0244, 0.4587, 0.1832, 0.7093, 0.2874, 0.9551,
        0.8489, 0.1560, 0.3212, 0.2144, 0.2841, 0.0630, 0.9778, 0.0212, 0.8164,
        0.6745, 0.2651, 0.7740, 0.0466, 0.4219, 0.0916, 0.2075, 0.4771, 0.6549,
        0.0735, 0.6748, 0.8197, 0.2675, 0.0482, 0.1787, 0.9859, 0.5532, 0.1647,
        0.7046, 0.8058, 0.7552, 0.1674, 0.3935, 0.0430, 0.2665, 0.6067, 0.2496,
        0.1711, 0.3226, 0.3504, 0.8985, 0.4125, 0.0925, 0.8231, 0.8535, 0.8478,
        0.2536, 0.6850, 0.6608, 0.6128, 0.0255, 0.6569, 0.0738, 0.8647, 0.2322,
        0.9898, 0.5044, 0.7879, 0.8705, 0.0973, 0.2900, 0.7294, 0.8847, 0.7572,
        0.4871, 0.8809, 0.5839, 0.4855, 0.8424, 0.4151, 0.1806, 0.7665, 0.4365,
        0.6867, 0.3397, 0.3951, 0.5472, 0.5545, 0.8930, 0.8970, 0.2972, 0.2406,
        0.3203, 0.3957, 0.1715, 0.1609, 0.8939, 0.0374, 0.8682, 0.4520, 0.2852,
        0.9323, 0.9132, 0.5007, 0.5879, 0.2878, 0.5277, 0.1378, 0.3752, 0.0059,
        0.4944, 0.9876, 0.7333, 0.2803, 0.4471, 0.3596, 0.8874, 0.6594, 0.5410,
        0.0277, 0.0497, 0.4526, 0.3456, 0.2889, 0.4981, 0.1150, 0.5470, 0.8293,
        0.9683, 0.1102, 0.0432, 0.0206, 0.0381, 0.0426, 0.1343, 0.0595, 0.1643,
        0.4930, 0.1606, 0.4333, 0.7708, 0.3279, 0.9765, 0.0809, 0.6337, 0.8330,
        0.7061, 0.5643, 0.9792, 0.7728, 0.9949, 0.6205, 0.7836, 0.3634, 0.4491,
        0.3759, 0.8197, 0.8402, 0.8870, 0.3647, 0.0718, 0.3802, 0.6333, 0.0564,
        0.1321, 0.9894, 0.4785, 0.2591, 0.5078, 0.8955, 0.1457, 0.3913, 0.7020,
        0.1685, 0.2133, 0.9725, 0.1179, 0.3458, 0.8330, 0.4897, 0.3802, 0.2729,
        0.3109, 0.2683, 0.3611, 0.9983, 0.9674, 0.8986, 0.0674, 0.4810, 0.2030,
        0.3708, 0.9974, 0.3354, 0.3416, 0.9956, 0.4438, 0.4523, 0.1212, 0.1906,
        0.0255, 0.3857, 0.0520, 0.8090, 0.0363, 0.5155, 0.5259, 0.5144, 0.0832,
        0.8416, 0.8666, 0.3573, 0.2119, 0.8180, 0.4281, 0.9585, 0.0069, 0.3688,
        0.8813, 0.9660, 0.4405, 0.7213, 0.9818, 0.0342, 0.7656, 0.4573, 0.2477,
        0.3124, 0.2173, 0.2723, 0.2149, 0.9469, 0.7091, 0.8051, 0.9815, 0.0416,
        0.3525, 0.7070, 0.9123, 0.1957, 0.4095, 0.8105, 0.4935, 0.7852, 0.9508,
        0.7854, 0.3267, 0.0761, 0.1353, 0.5961, 0.3199, 0.6699, 0.8500, 0.8540,
        0.4927, 0.4319, 0.5490, 0.8794, 0.4855, 0.4408, 0.2513, 0.3591, 0.4385,
        0.4902, 0.0892, 0.2645, 0.2993, 0.5301, 0.2470, 0.4180, 0.3924, 0.4231,
        0.0155, 0.0239, 0.6117, 0.5051, 0.5522, 0.8229, 0.3941, 0.9290, 0.2339,
        0.0214, 0.8480, 0.6003, 0.9120, 0.0334, 0.0822, 0.7023, 0.0906, 0.1074,
        0.8747, 0.0965, 0.5973, 0.8562, 0.5227, 0.5342, 0.5682, 0.7457, 0.4776,
        0.7218, 0.5008, 0.6378, 0.5541, 0.6418, 0.1443, 0.1458, 0.8786, 0.4283,
        0.2835, 0.6132, 0.8284, 0.9009, 0.5561, 0.5137, 0.9318, 0.0267, 0.2009,
        0.6635, 0.3267, 0.5239, 0.1676, 0.2327, 0.1248, 0.8706, 0.4100, 0.0529,
        0.8903, 0.8717, 0.7688, 0.2585, 0.3399, 0.7276, 0.4385, 0.6888, 0.6419,
        0.2661, 0.8262, 0.7331, 0.5433, 0.9399, 0.4117, 0.4899, 0.6666, 0.0826,
        0.1968, 0.6295, 0.4921, 0.3039, 0.5059, 0.8406, 0.6863, 0.1999, 0.8681,
        0.7958, 0.2988, 0.5588, 0.6630, 0.4348, 0.2735, 0.4761, 0.0994, 0.0803,
        0.1431, 0.9707, 0.3018, 0.3598, 0.6734, 0.6126, 0.1162, 0.2229, 0.1249,
        0.8871, 0.6972, 0.4470, 0.7034, 0.4932, 0.1183, 0.2348, 0.8528, 0.7901,
        0.2365, 0.7217, 0.5406, 0.1416, 0.9804, 0.7091, 0.3708, 0.4327, 0.0531,
        0.0861, 0.2463, 0.0912, 0.6666, 0.4180, 0.9266, 0.2631, 0.7023, 0.0398,
        0.0631, 0.6601, 0.6339, 0.6206, 0.1393, 0.1075, 0.6920, 0.6626, 0.8973,
        0.1839, 0.2475, 0.1521, 0.0381, 0.5855, 0.2973, 0.1848, 0.3025, 0.8042,
        0.5952, 0.6057, 0.5527, 0.7248, 0.0033, 0.3411, 0.8677, 0.9543, 0.6956,
        0.2909, 0.9458, 0.4611, 0.1876, 0.1012, 0.6692, 0.9081, 0.1122, 0.9392,
        0.8478, 0.6917, 0.6057, 0.6920, 0.1247, 0.9858, 0.3460, 0.8301, 0.8894,
        0.8431, 0.4964, 0.0289, 0.1298, 0.1918, 0.8065, 0.5335, 0.9905, 0.7099,
        0.6120, 0.2878, 0.2931, 0.8318, 0.9276, 0.9328, 0.3071, 0.3785, 0.5239,
        0.2914, 0.1401, 0.4540, 0.4798, 0.4797, 0.0380, 0.2156, 0.1642, 0.5507,
        0.0664, 0.8262, 0.9418, 0.0536, 0.2727, 0.9576, 0.4063, 0.4981, 0.4513,
        0.6310, 0.9909, 0.3513, 0.5842, 0.6780, 0.8629, 0.7755, 0.0898, 0.9114,
        0.0207, 0.1783, 0.1597, 0.8240, 0.9023, 0.0074, 0.7930, 0.8564, 0.4700,
        0.8839, 0.4839, 0.9852, 0.3291, 0.9607, 0.8842, 0.8725, 0.1717, 0.6004,
        0.0670, 0.8676, 0.6065, 0.6930, 0.8870, 0.2545, 0.1041, 0.5940, 0.5596,
        0.8877, 0.4002, 0.5495, 0.3640, 0.4373, 0.8292, 0.2008, 0.3124, 0.6308,
        0.2529, 0.1802, 0.5372, 0.9018, 0.0830, 0.3240, 0.6729, 0.9612, 0.9211,
        0.5371, 0.8745, 0.4602, 0.7666, 0.0433, 0.5461, 0.2115, 0.2959, 0.0351,
        0.8651, 0.7865, 0.2392, 0.1375, 0.7444, 0.6702, 0.1889, 0.0102, 0.2363,
        0.9406, 0.2144, 0.2174, 0.5765, 0.8715, 0.5440, 0.7480, 0.0387, 0.2754,
        0.7528, 0.4358, 0.1080, 0.8259, 0.0232, 0.2766, 0.4030, 0.6221, 0.5128,
        0.1035, 0.3966, 0.3859, 0.4088, 0.8898, 0.6106, 0.0241, 0.0442, 0.1680,
        0.3836, 0.8129, 0.4091, 0.7610, 0.7527, 0.7474, 0.2838, 0.3861, 0.3496,
        0.6985, 0.0842, 0.4432, 0.2829, 0.9554, 0.7354, 0.4623, 0.4193, 0.6449,
        0.1662, 0.3948, 0.1070, 0.4275, 0.6427, 0.6758, 0.1149, 0.9313, 0.3048,
        0.2237, 0.4992, 0.4688, 0.3633, 0.5445, 0.8166, 0.0392, 0.9118, 0.7784,
        0.4596, 0.5234, 0.0789, 0.1671, 0.0663, 0.6008, 0.4271, 0.6451, 0.8050,
        0.7993, 0.3750, 0.4266, 0.2093, 0.8230, 0.0515, 0.0785, 0.1407, 0.0502,
        0.1021, 0.0343, 0.0291, 0.0833, 0.4709, 0.7199, 0.6756, 0.3500, 0.7100,
        0.6334, 0.8984, 0.6105, 0.2101, 0.7228, 0.2321, 0.2186, 0.2271, 0.3792,
        0.3462, 0.7752, 0.9628, 0.4922, 0.3908, 0.7770, 0.0485, 0.5218, 0.1772,
        0.0367, 0.9492, 0.9352, 0.4897, 0.9790, 0.1704, 0.9757, 0.3399, 0.3952,
        0.2428, 0.3014, 0.1833, 0.0175, 0.9480, 0.3613, 0.3031, 0.1372, 0.4799,
        0.0364, 0.7588, 0.4608, 0.2652, 0.2054, 0.6034, 0.5563, 0.0053, 0.3368,
        0.7328, 0.5666, 0.2000, 0.4721, 0.5381, 0.9557, 0.0762, 0.4067, 0.8686,
        0.6698, 0.7660, 0.9169, 0.8401, 0.7283, 0.0271, 0.2323, 0.0811, 0.6277,
        0.8744, 0.9459, 0.9015, 0.6752, 0.7650, 0.6628, 0.4006, 0.5877, 0.0514,
        0.8610, 0.3106, 0.6999, 0.6773, 0.4738, 0.1838, 0.0942, 0.9465, 0.0689,
        0.3126, 0.7237, 0.6566, 0.4259, 0.1337, 0.8046, 0.2415, 0.9873, 0.9736,
        0.2487, 0.8346, 0.9100, 0.3429, 0.1321, 0.7593, 0.7780, 0.2588, 0.2804,
        0.3661, 0.3630, 0.7371, 0.5247, 0.9303, 0.2413, 0.2591, 0.3403, 0.0683,
        0.4428, 0.4089, 0.7018, 0.8541, 0.2662, 0.2819, 0.9080, 0.5924, 0.8527,
        0.8277, 0.0945, 0.3408, 0.0259, 0.8425, 0.3551, 0.9404, 0.6876, 0.3102,
        0.8169, 0.3289, 0.7174, 0.2404, 0.7087, 0.2562, 0.2022, 0.1705, 0.6359,
        0.7204, 0.0698, 0.1980, 0.7807, 0.0989, 0.0387, 0.5021, 0.9782, 0.0989,
        0.4415, 0.9582, 0.8193, 0.7433, 0.3606, 0.8234, 0.9470, 0.6152, 0.0739,
        0.0091, 0.3852, 0.6140, 0.8024, 0.3931, 0.6374, 0.7420, 0.8262, 0.5612,
        0.1429, 0.1118, 0.5879, 0.2417, 0.8952, 0.2698, 0.8374, 0.9325, 0.9897,
        0.7748, 0.0254, 0.8351, 0.5943, 0.9824, 0.2132, 0.6469, 0.8862, 0.9013,
        0.5097, 0.5300, 0.7497, 0.8371, 0.1307, 0.2927, 0.1760, 0.6744, 0.7508,
        0.7924, 0.9564, 0.8733, 0.8700, 0.9728, 0.1362, 0.3822, 0.7738, 0.7682,
        0.3459, 0.5163, 0.6223, 0.9129, 0.3179, 0.7660, 0.0849, 0.7594, 0.9258,
        0.3004, 0.5658, 0.1079, 0.0985, 0.3576, 0.8792, 0.2296, 0.2061, 0.9494,
        0.9141, 0.1866, 0.4255, 0.6605, 0.5622, 0.4929])]
>>> labelA
[tensor([0.7239, 0.1610, 0.6094, 0.8368, 0.1523, 0.1063, 0.6487, 0.8021, 0.0650,
        0.5950, 0.3393, 0.7012, 0.6868, 0.8905, 0.4100, 0.8173, 0.2271, 0.7572,
        0.9446, 0.4321, 0.5575, 0.4204, 0.8950, 0.2369, 0.1743, 0.8011, 0.3178,
        0.8098, 0.1318, 0.2499, 0.2979, 0.4248, 0.7016, 0.5042, 0.5122, 0.0894,
        0.6981, 0.9588, 0.9439, 0.6145, 0.1386, 0.0325, 0.6099, 0.5928, 0.1368,
        0.3560, 0.5814, 0.8894, 0.5715, 0.3138, 0.2881, 0.0041, 0.2198, 0.2518,
        0.7856, 0.9828, 0.0374, 0.1621, 0.8600, 0.9820, 0.9233, 0.1292, 0.3045,
        0.5753, 0.6036, 0.7019, 0.2679, 0.5477, 0.2112, 0.7881, 0.3429, 0.2112,
        0.3397, 0.6253, 0.2414, 0.0650, 0.4213, 0.0078, 0.5286, 0.1454, 0.5127,
        0.9211, 0.2263, 0.7103, 0.6328, 0.4127, 0.5828, 0.5850, 0.3128, 0.6189,
        0.0670, 0.5370, 0.3466, 0.8870, 0.0481, 0.4839, 0.0507, 0.1635, 0.6603,
        0.6537, 0.6107, 0.0907, 0.0952, 0.8440, 0.5431, 0.4123, 0.2333, 0.0709,
        0.3717, 0.5081, 0.6989, 0.7998, 0.4175, 0.4417, 0.4483, 0.4192, 0.4145,
        0.3055, 0.1455, 0.8435, 0.0244, 0.4587, 0.1832, 0.7093, 0.2874, 0.9551,
        0.8489, 0.1560, 0.3212, 0.2144, 0.2841, 0.0630, 0.9778, 0.0212, 0.8164,
        0.6745, 0.2651, 0.7740, 0.0466, 0.4219, 0.0916, 0.2075, 0.4771, 0.6549,
        0.0735, 0.6748, 0.8197, 0.2675, 0.0482, 0.1787, 0.9859, 0.5532, 0.1647,
        0.7046, 0.8058, 0.7552, 0.1674, 0.3935, 0.0430, 0.2665, 0.6067, 0.2496,
        0.1711, 0.3226, 0.3504, 0.8985, 0.4125, 0.0925, 0.8231, 0.8535, 0.8478,
        0.2536, 0.6850, 0.6608, 0.6128, 0.0255, 0.6569, 0.0738, 0.8647, 0.2322,
        0.9898, 0.5044, 0.7879, 0.8705, 0.0973, 0.2900, 0.7294, 0.8847, 0.7572,
        0.4871, 0.8809, 0.5839, 0.4855, 0.8424, 0.4151, 0.1806, 0.7665, 0.4365,
        0.6867, 0.3397, 0.3951, 0.5472, 0.5545, 0.8930, 0.8970, 0.2972, 0.2406,
        0.3203, 0.3957, 0.1715, 0.1609, 0.8939, 0.0374, 0.8682, 0.4520, 0.2852,
        0.9323, 0.9132, 0.5007, 0.5879, 0.2878, 0.5277, 0.1378, 0.3752, 0.0059,
        0.4944, 0.9876, 0.7333, 0.2803, 0.4471, 0.3596, 0.8874, 0.6594, 0.5410,
        0.0277, 0.0497, 0.4526, 0.3456, 0.2889, 0.4981, 0.1150, 0.5470, 0.8293,
        0.9683, 0.1102, 0.0432, 0.0206, 0.0381, 0.0426, 0.1343, 0.0595, 0.1643,
        0.4930, 0.1606, 0.4333, 0.7708, 0.3279, 0.9765, 0.0809, 0.6337, 0.8330,
        0.7061, 0.5643, 0.9792, 0.7728, 0.9949, 0.6205, 0.7836, 0.3634, 0.4491,
        0.3759, 0.8197, 0.8402, 0.8870, 0.3647, 0.0718, 0.3802, 0.6333, 0.0564,
        0.1321, 0.9894, 0.4785, 0.2591, 0.5078, 0.8955, 0.1457, 0.3913, 0.7020,
        0.1685, 0.2133, 0.9725, 0.1179, 0.3458, 0.8330, 0.4897, 0.3802, 0.2729,
        0.3109, 0.2683, 0.3611, 0.9983, 0.9674, 0.8986, 0.0674, 0.4810, 0.2030,
        0.3708, 0.9974, 0.3354, 0.3416, 0.9956, 0.4438, 0.4523, 0.1212, 0.1906,
        0.0255, 0.3857, 0.0520, 0.8090, 0.0363, 0.5155, 0.5259, 0.5144, 0.0832,
        0.8416, 0.8666, 0.3573, 0.2119, 0.8180, 0.4281, 0.9585, 0.0069, 0.3688,
        0.8813, 0.9660, 0.4405, 0.7213, 0.9818, 0.0342, 0.7656, 0.4573, 0.2477,
        0.3124, 0.2173, 0.2723, 0.2149, 0.9469, 0.7091, 0.8051, 0.9815, 0.0416,
        0.3525, 0.7070, 0.9123, 0.1957, 0.4095, 0.8105, 0.4935, 0.7852, 0.9508,
        0.7854, 0.3267, 0.0761, 0.1353, 0.5961, 0.3199, 0.6699, 0.8500, 0.8540,
        0.4927, 0.4319, 0.5490, 0.8794, 0.4855, 0.4408, 0.2513, 0.3591, 0.4385,
        0.4902, 0.0892, 0.2645, 0.2993, 0.5301, 0.2470, 0.4180, 0.3924, 0.4231,
        0.0155, 0.0239, 0.6117, 0.5051, 0.5522, 0.8229, 0.3941, 0.9290, 0.2339,
        0.0214, 0.8480, 0.6003, 0.9120, 0.0334, 0.0822, 0.7023, 0.0906, 0.1074,
        0.8747, 0.0965, 0.5973, 0.8562, 0.5227, 0.5342, 0.5682, 0.7457, 0.4776,
        0.7218, 0.5008, 0.6378, 0.5541, 0.6418, 0.1443, 0.1458, 0.8786, 0.4283,
        0.2835, 0.6132, 0.8284, 0.9009, 0.5561, 0.5137, 0.9318, 0.0267, 0.2009,
        0.6635, 0.3267, 0.5239, 0.1676, 0.2327, 0.1248, 0.8706, 0.4100, 0.0529,
        0.8903, 0.8717, 0.7688, 0.2585, 0.3399, 0.7276, 0.4385, 0.6888, 0.6419,
        0.2661, 0.8262, 0.7331, 0.5433, 0.9399, 0.4117, 0.4899, 0.6666, 0.0826,
        0.1968, 0.6295, 0.4921, 0.3039, 0.5059, 0.8406, 0.6863, 0.1999, 0.8681,
        0.7958, 0.2988, 0.5588, 0.6630, 0.4348, 0.2735, 0.4761, 0.0994, 0.0803,
        0.1431, 0.9707, 0.3018, 0.3598, 0.6734, 0.6126, 0.1162, 0.2229, 0.1249,
        0.8871, 0.6972, 0.4470, 0.7034, 0.4932, 0.1183, 0.2348, 0.8528, 0.7901,
        0.2365, 0.7217, 0.5406, 0.1416, 0.9804, 0.7091, 0.3708, 0.4327, 0.0531,
        0.0861, 0.2463, 0.0912, 0.6666, 0.4180, 0.9266, 0.2631, 0.7023, 0.0398,
        0.0631, 0.6601, 0.6339, 0.6206, 0.1393, 0.1075, 0.6920, 0.6626, 0.8973,
        0.1839, 0.2475, 0.1521, 0.0381, 0.5855, 0.2973, 0.1848, 0.3025, 0.8042,
        0.5952, 0.6057, 0.5527, 0.7248, 0.0033, 0.3411, 0.8677, 0.9543, 0.6956,
        0.2909, 0.9458, 0.4611, 0.1876, 0.1012, 0.6692, 0.9081, 0.1122, 0.9392,
        0.8478, 0.6917, 0.6057, 0.6920, 0.1247, 0.9858, 0.3460, 0.8301, 0.8894,
        0.8431, 0.4964, 0.0289, 0.1298, 0.1918, 0.8065, 0.5335, 0.9905, 0.7099,
        0.6120, 0.2878, 0.2931, 0.8318, 0.9276, 0.9328, 0.3071, 0.3785, 0.5239,
        0.2914, 0.1401, 0.4540, 0.4798, 0.4797, 0.0380, 0.2156, 0.1642, 0.5507,
        0.0664, 0.8262, 0.9418, 0.0536, 0.2727, 0.9576, 0.4063, 0.4981, 0.4513,
        0.6310, 0.9909, 0.3513, 0.5842, 0.6780, 0.8629, 0.7755, 0.0898, 0.9114,
        0.0207, 0.1783, 0.1597, 0.8240, 0.9023, 0.0074, 0.7930, 0.8564, 0.4700,
        0.8839, 0.4839, 0.9852, 0.3291, 0.9607, 0.8842, 0.8725, 0.1717, 0.6004,
        0.0670, 0.8676, 0.6065, 0.6930, 0.8870, 0.2545, 0.1041, 0.5940, 0.5596,
        0.8877, 0.4002, 0.5495, 0.3640, 0.4373, 0.8292, 0.2008, 0.3124, 0.6308,
        0.2529, 0.1802, 0.5372, 0.9018, 0.0830, 0.3240, 0.6729, 0.9612, 0.9211,
        0.5371, 0.8745, 0.4602, 0.7666, 0.0433, 0.5461, 0.2115, 0.2959, 0.0351,
        0.8651, 0.7865, 0.2392, 0.1375, 0.7444, 0.6702, 0.1889, 0.0102, 0.2363,
        0.9406, 0.2144, 0.2174, 0.5765, 0.8715, 0.5440, 0.7480, 0.0387, 0.2754,
        0.7528, 0.4358, 0.1080, 0.8259, 0.0232, 0.2766, 0.4030, 0.6221, 0.5128,
        0.1035, 0.3966, 0.3859, 0.4088, 0.8898, 0.6106, 0.0241, 0.0442, 0.1680,
        0.3836, 0.8129, 0.4091, 0.7610, 0.7527, 0.7474, 0.2838, 0.3861, 0.3496,
        0.6985, 0.0842, 0.4432, 0.2829, 0.9554, 0.7354, 0.4623, 0.4193, 0.6449,
        0.1662, 0.3948, 0.1070, 0.4275, 0.6427, 0.6758, 0.1149, 0.9313, 0.3048,
        0.2237, 0.4992, 0.4688, 0.3633, 0.5445, 0.8166, 0.0392, 0.9118, 0.7784,
        0.4596, 0.5234, 0.0789, 0.1671, 0.0663, 0.6008, 0.4271, 0.6451, 0.8050,
        0.7993, 0.3750, 0.4266, 0.2093, 0.8230, 0.0515, 0.0785, 0.1407, 0.0502,
        0.1021, 0.0343, 0.0291, 0.0833, 0.4709, 0.7199, 0.6756, 0.3500, 0.7100,
        0.6334, 0.8984, 0.6105, 0.2101, 0.7228, 0.2321, 0.2186, 0.2271, 0.3792,
        0.3462, 0.7752, 0.9628, 0.4922, 0.3908, 0.7770, 0.0485, 0.5218, 0.1772,
        0.0367, 0.9492, 0.9352, 0.4897, 0.9790, 0.1704, 0.9757, 0.3399, 0.3952,
        0.2428, 0.3014, 0.1833, 0.0175, 0.9480, 0.3613, 0.3031, 0.1372, 0.4799,
        0.0364, 0.7588, 0.4608, 0.2652, 0.2054, 0.6034, 0.5563, 0.0053, 0.3368,
        0.7328, 0.5666, 0.2000, 0.4721, 0.5381, 0.9557, 0.0762, 0.4067, 0.8686,
        0.6698, 0.7660, 0.9169, 0.8401, 0.7283, 0.0271, 0.2323, 0.0811, 0.6277,
        0.8744, 0.9459, 0.9015, 0.6752, 0.7650, 0.6628, 0.4006, 0.5877, 0.0514,
        0.8610, 0.3106, 0.6999, 0.6773, 0.4738, 0.1838, 0.0942, 0.9465, 0.0689,
        0.3126, 0.7237, 0.6566, 0.4259, 0.1337, 0.8046, 0.2415, 0.9873, 0.9736,
        0.2487, 0.8346, 0.9100, 0.3429, 0.1321, 0.7593, 0.7780, 0.2588, 0.2804,
        0.3661, 0.3630, 0.7371, 0.5247, 0.9303, 0.2413, 0.2591, 0.3403, 0.0683,
        0.4428, 0.4089, 0.7018, 0.8541, 0.2662, 0.2819, 0.9080, 0.5924, 0.8527,
        0.8277, 0.0945, 0.3408, 0.0259, 0.8425, 0.3551, 0.9404, 0.6876, 0.3102,
        0.8169, 0.3289, 0.7174, 0.2404, 0.7087, 0.2562, 0.2022, 0.1705, 0.6359,
        0.7204, 0.0698, 0.1980, 0.7807, 0.0989, 0.0387, 0.5021, 0.9782, 0.0989,
        0.4415, 0.9582, 0.8193, 0.7433, 0.3606, 0.8234, 0.9470, 0.6152, 0.0739,
        0.0091, 0.3852, 0.6140, 0.8024, 0.3931, 0.6374, 0.7420, 0.8262, 0.5612,
        0.1429, 0.1118, 0.5879, 0.2417, 0.8952, 0.2698, 0.8374, 0.9325, 0.9897,
        0.7748, 0.0254, 0.8351, 0.5943, 0.9824, 0.2132, 0.6469, 0.8862, 0.9013,
        0.5097, 0.5300, 0.7497, 0.8371, 0.1307, 0.2927, 0.1760, 0.6744, 0.7508,
        0.7924, 0.9564, 0.8733, 0.8700, 0.9728, 0.1362, 0.3822, 0.7738, 0.7682,
        0.3459, 0.5163, 0.6223, 0.9129, 0.3179, 0.7660, 0.0849, 0.7594, 0.9258,
        0.3004, 0.5658, 0.1079, 0.0985, 0.3576, 0.8792, 0.2296, 0.2061, 0.9494,
        0.9141, 0.1866, 0.4255, 0.6605, 0.5622, 0.4929])]
>>> labelA[0] == labelB[0]
tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       dtype=torch.uint8)
```

I know this is a lot, so let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that I have redefined them. Thank you for your kind help!